# Erro ao tentar efetuar Start do Tomcat no Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Tenho a configuração abaixo:

- Eclipse: Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
- Apache Tomcat 8.5.33 Server

Acessei o endereço http://localhost:8080/ sem nenhum erro.

Ao tentar efetuar Start no Eclipse recebo a mensagem abaixo:

> -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
>   in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

Comment: Como no erro  é  informado  Tomcat 8.5\endorsed  não é suportado,  e ele só será suportado com modulos atualizados, o  Tomcat  já está na versão   9.0.11 tente atualiza-lo isso deve resolver seu problema como  relatado aqui >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226250/could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine-tomcat-server-on-mac-os     e você pode baixar a nova versão aqui http://tomcat.apache.org/

Comment: Após instalar o Tomcat 9.0 e tentar novamente, obtive a mensagem: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: conseguiu algo com a atualização  ?

Comment: Recebi também a mensagem "An internal error has occurred. java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: esse erro é comum no  java, de uma  olhada aqui  de motivos que podem ser https://www.devmedia.com.br/java-lang-nullpointerexception-dica/28677

Comment: creio  que agora seja algum erro relacionado  em  seu  codigo

Comment: Não criei nenhum projeto Web ainda. Mas vou pesquisar...

Comment: Boa noite. Instalei a versão JDK 8 e consegui startar o Tomcat8 no Eclipse Oxygen. Obrigado.

Comment: por nada,  bons trabalhos